# Mysql : I need to search record where searched text is matched with third word

Tags: mysql

I need to search record where searched text is matched with third word from database record.

Example : Suppose i have three records in description field

```
This is alex from Usa
This is Michael from India
This is xyz  from Canada
```

I want that what i search should be check in third word only. How is it possible in mysql ? How to write query like that ?

Comment: Remember that searched text must be check in third word only and should not return result if it is matched into any other words.

Comment: Checkout mysql full text search.

Comment: I think full text search is used to search like natural language search. But i want to search word only from specific positioned words. So there should be other options.

Comment: You know that this is super unrelyable? How about `this is mary jane from italy`? or `My name is peter from france`?

Comment: one matched you need the full row to be returned or only the matched word?

Comment: i need to return full row only. but comparison must be within third word only. thats it.

Comment: Example which i have given is just for sample. Actually in real there will specific code where third word has special meaning where i have to perform search condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substring_index

```
select * from my_table 
where  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,' ',3),' ',-1) =  'Your_text';
```

or if needed use like

```
select * from my_table 
where  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,' ',3),' ',-1) like  '%Your_text%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **REGEXP_REPLACE** if you DB this can:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('This is alex from Usa. and mor Text','^\\w+ \\w+ \(\\w+\).*$','\\1');
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [bb]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('This is alex from Usa. and mor Text','^\\w+ \\w+ \(\\w+\).*$','\\1');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('This is alex from Usa. and more Text','^\\w+ \\w+ \(\\w+\).*$','\\1') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| alex                                                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
```

see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/

You also can create a virtual persitent field in (MariaDB) your table, that automatic hold only the 3 word. so you can use a index on this field

create table like this

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
     a INT NOT NULL,
     yourtext VARCHAR(32),
     c INT AS (a mod 10) VIRTUAL,
     word VARCHAR(20) AS 
      (REGEXP_REPLACE(yourtext,'^\\w+ \\w+ \(\\w+\).*$','\\1')) PERSISTENT);
```